# Datatable not accepting PHP Echo as Data Ajax PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, datatables

I'm populating my table by using PHP and using [Datatable](https://datatables.net/) for pagination and filters. I have an Android application that is sending values to my database. What I want is a real-time Update to my table. I tried using AJAX to make it real time by calling the PHP script via interval. It is working fine but the pagination and filters is not working.

**Dont mind the Table Heading**

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Resident</th>
            <th>Complaints</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Date Issued</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="comTbl">
     </tbody>
</table> 

<script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#comTbl").load("fetchPresident.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                      $("#comTbl").load('fetchPresident.php?randval='+ Math.random());
                    }, 9000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]]
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

//Connect to database
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','brm_dbs');
if (!$connection) {
  die('Could not connect to database ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}

//Fetch the data from tables
$query="SELECT * FROM presidents";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<tr><td>" . $row['f_name']."</td>
         <td>" . $row['l_name'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $row['party'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $row['joined_office'] . "</td>
         <td>" . $row['left_office'] . "</td>
         </tr>";
}
// $output[] = array ("<tbody> <tr>","<td>",$row[0],"</td>","<td>",$row[1],"</td>","<td>",$row[2],"</td>","<td>",$row[3],"<td>","<td>",$row[4],"</td>","</tr> </tbdoy>");

//Close database connection 
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Already tried echo-ing the table but the **Datatable** can't read the **ID**.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialise the dataTable after each refresh / reload :

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

function loadTable() {
   $("#comTbl").load("fetchPresident.php");
   $('#myTable').DataTable({
      destroy: true,
      lengthMenu: [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]]
   })
}

loadTable();

var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
    loadTable()
}, 9000);
```

[**`destroy`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) makes it possible to reinitialise the table without errors.

Comment: i just your codes to my code the **destroy** make it works thanks :)